# Converting C code to assembly

Tags: c, assembly

I needed some help converting this C code into assembly:

Idea is:

```
sz = length of v
k = allocate array of ints, length v
if type = 0
 k[i] = length v[i]
else
 k[i] = sum v[i]
```

sort k the simplest swapping way:
each time when k[i] and k[j] is swapped, swap v[i] and v[j] too

deallocate k

```
gcc -O0 -S test.c
```

(compile to assembler)

Comment: You want us to write the C code? What is your problem?

Comment: I need help converting C code into assembly

Comment: This is not a c code, it's barely an algorithm. Do you have some ready C code, or that's what you need?

Comment: Also, where did you meet a problem?

Comment: For one thing, you'll have to be more specific than "assembly".  What is your target architecture?

Comment: Yes i need some help in figuring out how to implement the idea into C, and then converting it into asm. The target architecture is NASM

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, please mark it as such. If not, why do you want to turn it into assembler?

Comment: Cannot determine the size of an array nor the number of valid items in the array only by accessing the array.  This makes converting to assembly very difficult.

Comment: You have to add some more details to the question. Formalize it a bit. it's hard to understand the purpose this way. (e.g. what do you mean by `k[i] = length v[i]` ?)

Comment: That's some bad bad pseudo-code.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a C code, its not even an algorithm just an idea.
You can convert your C code to assembly,

But if you're using I/O functions like printf/scanf or memory allocation functions, Its not pure assembly but its dependent  on C and OS libraries. So it wont compile on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Write up your C code into a function.

Read your compiler documentation on how to generate an assembly language listing.

Done.